# How can I set up 'bake' with MAMP on OS X with projects in 'Sites'?

Tags: cakephp, mamp, cakephp-bake, .profile

I'm trying to set up 'cake bake' on OS X. I'm using MAMP and every time I try to 'bake', I get this:

-bash: cake: command not found

I have the Apress Beginning CakePHP book, but the suggestions in that book aren't working for me. In the Apress, book, he suggests the following solution in .profile

alias cake="php ~/Sites/blog/cake/console/cake.php"

I've also found some other suggestions:
(put an alias in .profile)

alias cake="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/php /Users/fabian/Sites/miapp/cake/console/cake.php"

alias cake="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/php /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake/console/cake.php"

I've also tried this in terminal:
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/php ~/Sites/miapp/cake/console/cake.php bake

...but this didn't work either.

I also tried the solution in this YouTube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOBO-kEakQ0 , but that didn't work either.

So...how could I get 'bake' working with MAMP on OS X with my projects in 'Sites'?

Cheers!

Sam

Comment: Try /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what cake bake is, but it looks like it can't find cake on your path.  After you set the alias in your .profile did you issue:

```
source ~/.profile
```

to update the settings in it?